# Delete past versions of Web Contents that have more than N versions

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have a Liferay 6.2 server with a site containing many Web Contents.

## Problem

Over the years, the server has become very slow at times, even triggering an OutOfMemoryException recently. The MySQL slow query log shows that this is due to some Web Contents having thousands of versions.

## Goal

As we don't care much about versions, we are considering trowing out all old versions, but as a first remedy to avoid further OutOfMemory exceptions, we want to do this:

**Remove all past versions of Web Contents that have more than 100 versions**

How to do?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the script console (in Server Administration), set it to "Groovy", paste the script below, insert the group ids of the relevant sites (aka. site ids, found using the Liferay web interface), then execute:

```
import com.liferay.portlet.journal.service.JournalArticleServiceUtil
import com.liferay.portlet.journal.service.JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil
import com.liferay.portlet.journal.model.JournalArticle

/**
 * Delete past versions of articles with too many versions.
 */

/**
 * Configuration.
 */
MAX_NUMBER_OF_VERSIONS = 100
DELETIONS_LIMIT=-1 // Only delete this number of versions, in total. Useful for tests. -1 = no limit
CHUNK=10 // In order to avoid memory load, everything is performed chunk by chunk, with this size.
sites = [20182, 21987]

/**
 * Main.
 */
sites.each {
  println "\n# Site " + it
  deletePastVersionsOfArticlesWithTooManyVersions(it)
}

/**
 * Delete past versions of articles with too many versions in the given site.
 */
def deletePastVersionsOfArticlesWithTooManyVersions(groupId) {
  List<JournalArticle> articlesWithTooManyVersions = findArticlesWithTooManyVersions(groupId);
  println "\nDeleting all past versions of " + articlesWithTooManyVersions.size() + " articles with too many versions"
  articlesWithTooManyVersions.each {
    deletePastVersions(groupId, it);
  }
}

/**
  * Returns the list of articles with to many versions in the given site, as a List<JournalArticle>
  */
def findArticlesWithTooManyVersions(groupId) {
  List<JournalArticle> result = new ArrayList<JournalArticle>()

  int count = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getArticlesCount(groupId)
  for (int start=0; start<count; start+=CHUNK) {
    List<JournalArticle> versions = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getArticles(groupId, start, start+CHUNK, null)
    println "Page start:" + start + " size:" + versions.size()

    // Process this page
    versions.each { version ->
      // Ignore documents that are in the recycle bin.
      if (version.isInTrash()) {
        return // Equivalent of continue for closures.
      }
      // We only need to process each Web Content once, but we get one JournalArticle per version.
      // The trick here is to only process the JournalArticle if it is the latest version, as each Web Content has exactly one latest version.
      if(JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.isLatestVersion(groupId,version.getArticleId(), version.getVersion())){
        println "Checking article " + version.getArticleId()
        numberOfVersions = JournalArticleServiceUtil.getArticlesCountByArticleId(groupId, version.getArticleId());
        if(numberOfVersions > MAX_NUMBER_OF_VERSIONS) {
          println "JournalArticle " + version.getArticleId() + " has more than " + MAX_NUMBER_OF_VERSIONS + " versions."
          result.add(version);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return result
}

/**
  * Delete all past versions of the given article.
  */
def deletePastVersions(groupId, article) {
  int count = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getArticlesCount(groupId, article.getArticleId())
  int numberOfNecessaryIterations = 1 + count/(CHUNK-1) // Plus 1 for the remainder. Minus 1 to account for the worse case where the latest version appears in all chunks.
  println "Deleting " + (count - 1) + " versions of article " + article.getArticleId() + " in " + numberOfNecessaryIterations + " iterations."
  for (int iteration=0; iteration<=numberOfNecessaryIterations; iteration++) {
  // Paging is refreshed after deletion so we must always get the first elements.
  List<JournalArticle> versions = JournalArticleServiceUtil.getArticlesByArticleId(groupId, article.getArticleId(), 0, CHUNK, null)

    println "Iteration " + iteration + " Deleting " + versions.size() + " past versions of article " + article.getArticleId() // Actually one less if this chunk contains the latest version.
    for(version in versions) {
       if(JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.isLatestVersion(groupId, version.getArticleId(), version.getVersion())) {
         println "Skipping the latest version." // The latest version must NOT be deleted.
         continue; // Proceed to the next version of this chunk.
      }
      // Delete this version
      println "Deleting article " + version.getArticleId() + " version " + version.getVersion() + " " + new Date()
      if (DELETIONS_LIMIT!=0) {
        DELETIONS_LIMIT--
        JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.deleteArticle(groupId, version.getArticleId(), version.getVersion(), null,null)
        println "Deletion performed"
      }
      if (DELETIONS_LIMIT==0){
        return // Exit the method
      }
    }
  }
}
```